# Have to avoid all records having more than one occurrence using control file of a SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

I want to avoid all the records to be inserted into a table using SQL Loader. The table in which we are inserting has a primary key over 3 columns. Whenever duplicate occurred, code gets failed with a primary key violation.

I have a requirement to skip/avoid all the record having more than one occurrence in the data file while inserting using control file. Could anyone please help me out here?

Is there any way to skip those records by adding some conditions in control file itself?

Comment: How should we interpret your requirements?  Suppose there are 3 records in the data file with the same primary key information, not conflicting with any existing record. Is your requirement that none of those three should be loaded? Or is it acceptable that the first would be loaded (there's no conflicting record), but the second and third would be rejected? If it is the former (none of the records should be loaded), I'm not sure whether there's a way with instructions to SQL Loader. You could, however, preprocess the file to remove such repeated records. Not too easy, but not too hard either.

Comment: What if you first load your file in a temporary_table then load it in your final_table after filtering out all unwanted records.

Comment: if you wish to remodel then you can insert from a select statement such as `SELECT a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, b.c4 FROM temp_table a LEFT JOIN temp_table b ON (a.c1 = b.c1 AND a.c2 = b.c2 AND a.c3 = b.c3) GROUP BY a.c1,a.c2,a.c3,b.c4 HAVING COUNT(a.c1) = 1`  .

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems that you're looking for a problem, while there's no problem at all.

- there's a table
- it has a primary key constraint set
- there's a file with data, some of them are duplicates (by the meaning of primary key columns)
- loading session begins
- rows that satisfy all conditions are successfully loaded into the table
- rows that violate *anything* (primary key constraint included) are not loaded

  - it (the error) is recorded in the `.log` file
  - those rows are now in the `.bad` file
- once the loading is done, table contains only distinct rows

Just in case you didn't know, there's the `errors` parameter; its value is integer, and it shows how many errors you want to allow:

- default is 50
- if you don't want to allow any errors, set it to 0
- if you want to allow any number of errors, set it to a very high value

So, what is the problem? I don't see any.

---

As it seems that - in case of duplicates - you don't want to load *any* of those rows as you don't know which one is correct, I don't think that SQL Loader is capable of doing that.

One option is to switch to **external table** which has the input file as a source and acts as an "ordinary" table and lets you write `SELECT` statements directly, without previously loading data into the database. It enables you to skip duplicates, e.g.

```
insert into target_table (col1, col2, ...)
  select col1, col2, ...
  from external_table a
  where (a.pkcol1, a.pkcol2, pkcol3) not in 
        (select b.pkcol1, b.pkcol2, b.pkcol3
         from external_table b
         group by b.pkcol1, b.pkcol2, b.pkcol3
         having count(*) > 1
        );
```

Or, you could **disable primary key constraint**, load data as you do it now (including duplicates), and then delete all duplicates, e.g.

```
delete from target_table a
      where (a.pkcol1, a.pkcol2, pkcol3) in 
            (select b.pkcol1, b.pkcol2, b.pkcol3
             from target_table b
             group by b.pkcol1, b.pkcol2, b.pkcol3
             having count(*) > 1
            );
```

Then re-enable the primary key constraint.

Comment: One interpretation of "the problem" could be "there are 3 records in the data file with the same primary key information — and none of those three should be loaded".  In your scenario, I think that the first would be loaded (there's no conflicting record), but the second and third would be rejected.  And, under my hypothesis, that isn't what the user wants.

Comment: Maybe, @Jonathan. Although, that just doesn't make much sense to me. OK, you don't want duplicates, that's OK. But why wouldn't you load row which doesn't violate the constraint? What's wrong with it? We'll see what the OP says (if anything).

Comment: If you don't know which of three statements is true, it may well be best to keep all three out of the database, rather than insert one which turns out to be false.  It's not a common scenario; it is a plausible scenario (IMO, of course).  But you're 100% correct that waiting on the OP for clarification is, at this stage, the only sensible option.  I'm not holding my breath, though.

Comment: Yeah you got it correct. Out of three statement in data file having same primary key information, we are not sure which one is correct. So I want to avoid/skip all these three records to being loaded.  Pls suggest

Comment: I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: @littlefoot Thanks for your precious time... But my requirement is only to skip these records at the time of loading the data only using sql loader.. If possible??   Thanks again for a quick response

Comment: You're welcome. As I said: as far as I know, SQL Loader can't do that.

Comment: Can we call a function/store procedure in the control file of a sql loader??

Comment: Functions - yes. Procedures - no.